# How to I set a time to live (TTL) for a specific line record within a hash key in a Redis database using Spring Boot and RedisTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, redis

I have an **EmployeeDaoImpl** class that has a **`saveEmployee`** method which uses the **`putIfAbsent`** method of **`hashOperations`** to store the **JSON** string in Redis.

```
@Service
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements IEmployeeDao {

    private static final String MAPPING_KEY = "EMPLOYEES_REG_TEMP_RECORDS";
    
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;
    @Resource(name = "stringRedisTemplate")  // 'stringRedisTemplate' is defined as a Bean in AppConfig.java
    private HashOperations<String, String, String> hashOperations;
    
    public EmployeeDaoImpl(ObjectMapper objectMapper, StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.stringRedisTemplate = stringRedisTemplate;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(Employee emp) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(emp);
        hashOperations.putIfAbsent(MAPPING_KEY, emp.getRequestRefId(), json);
    }

}
```

This screenshot is how the employee record is saved in Redis
[image]

I am able to expire the key this way

```
stringRedisTemplate.expire(key, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

But now I want to be able to set TTL for every single line record in the **EMPLOYEES_REG_TEMP_RECORDS** hash key without expiring the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields within a Hash in Redis cannot be expired. Redis only supports expiration on keys, not values within a key.

Comment: Guy Royse - Is that explicitly stated in the Redis documentation ? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the docs

Comment: The first line of the [EXPIRE](https://redis.io/commands/expire/) command documentation states "Set a timeout on *key*.". What constitutes a key is a common point of confusion with Redis—particularly with Hashes. Keys are the top level things that you store in Redis—it's a key-value store after all. Fields in a Hash are not keys. They are part of the data structure—a hash table in this case—that is stored in a key. This is also true for members of a Set, items in a List, events in a Stream, etc. The members and the items and the events are not keys, just parts of data structure stored within.